# Accessing Javascript json nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, tostring

I have a json that looks like this

```
{
  "1": {
    "average percent match": 0.2916666667, 
    "match counts": 1.0, 
    "confidence": 0.25
  }, 
  "0": {
    "average percent match": 0.25, 
    "match counts": 1.0, 
    "confidence": 0.25 
  },
}
```

I tried accessing the values in the json this way.

```
JSON.stringify(tlist.toString("utf8"))

        for(var i = 0; i < tlist.length; i++){
        var totalCity = tlist[i]['match counts'];
        console.log(totalCity)
      }
```

But i get an error that says undefined. Can anyone please point me to the problem?

Thanks you.

Comment: what do you mean by that: tlist.toString("utf8") what is ilist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input object is **not** an array  (or an array like object). Hence it hasn't any property called `length`. It's just an object literal with key/value pairs. So you have to parse it as you would have done with every other valid json and then loop through it's keys, like below:

```js
var input = "{\"1\": { \"average percent match\": 0.2916666667, \"match counts\": 1.0, \"confidence\": 0.25  }, \"0\": { \"average percent match\": 0.25, \"match counts\": 1.0, \"confidence\": 0.25 } }";

var obj = JSON.parse(input);

for(var key in obj){
    var totalCity = obj[key]['match counts'];
    console.log(totalCity);
}
```

**Update**

Generally when we loop through the keys of an object, as correctly Patrick pointed out in his comment, we follow the pattern below:

```
for(var key in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        // ....
    }
}
```

We do need this extra check, in order to avoid enumerating the properties that are defined on the object in the prototype chain of `obj`. At this case, since you object is a simple object whose **proto** is the Object, this is not needed. This is the reason I didn't include it.

For an in depth analysis of this, please ave a look at the following links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: When using the `for ... in` it's recommended to use `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)`, as the `in` operator will also check the prototype chain. [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

Comment: @PatrickBarr You are absolutely correct. Intentionally, I didn't include it here, because I assumed that the structure of the json is the one the OP has posted. I will update correspondingly my answer, in order to avoid any created misconfusion. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

That's not an array. You will have to access with it's key.

```
var x = {
  "0": {a: 'b'},
  "1": {a: 'b'},
}

for(key in x) {
  console.log(x[key]) //outputs {a: 'b'}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key values in your object are `string` typed:

```
{   // Keys wrapped in "" are strings
    "1": { ... },
    "2": { ... }
}
```

Even though javascript is a non-strictly typed language, it still has internal types, and objects won't attempt to convert the accessing key types, they will perform a strict check on the keys to determine whether it exists. When a strict check occurs, the value is not only taken into consideration, but so is the type; it's the difference between `==` and `===`, for a `===` to evaluate to `true` both the value AND the type have to match.

But when you go to access them in your loop, you're trying to access with a `number` type:

```
// i is defined as the number 0, and incremented by 1 on each iteration
for(var i = 0; i < tlist.length; i++){
    var totalCity = tlist[i]['match counts'];
    ...
}
```

But don't fret, you can still keep your loop, you just need to convert `i` to the correct type when you're accessing your object!

```
for(var i = 0; i < tlist.length; i++){
    // Adding an empty string to a number will convert said number into a string
    var totalCity = tlist[i + '']['match counts'];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:  Please put a link to jquery, or use the script link below.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script> 

var data = {
           "1": {
               "average percent match": 0.2916666667,
               "match counts": 1.0,
               "confidence": 0.25
           },
           "0": {
               "average percent match": 0.25,
               "match counts": 1.0,
               "confidence": 0.25
           },
       }
       var total =0;
       $.each(data, function (i, item) {
           total += item["match counts"];
       });
       alert("Total of match counts is: " + total);
```